# Show all Countries exept one in where

Tags: ssas, mdx, windows-server-2008-r2

I want to display all countries except USA, how should I write in the MDX code, inside of where statement?

Another example is to show all year except 2006.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use except for this.

All countries except US:

```
 {Except([Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].members,
     [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[United States])}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or a shorter version:

```
WHERE
   -{[Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[United States]}
```